# Excel: Find any partial match between a cell and an entire column of values

Tags: excel, vba, formula

To provide a very basic example:

## Column 1 | Column 2

```
               AN-K10LP / BQC-XVZ100001
               AN-K10LP / BQC-XVZ100001
               Whatever
               AN-K10LP / BQC-XVZ100001
               Whatever
               Whatever
               BQC-XVZ100001 / AN-K10LP
               AN-K10LP / BQC-XVZ100001
```

So does any part of B1 (AN-K10LP / BQC-XVZ100001) exist in the range of column B? And if so, enter in the value of B1 in A1. This would need to be dynamic to where I could drag the formula down and find all of them.

I'm looking for semi-matching cells. They will usually contain the same value, just switched around like that. Or just contain a portion of it. And I need to merge all of them to take the same value.

Comment: "Any part" means "any 'word'"? Eg: the substring "K10LP" might appear in other cells, but might not be what you're looking for...  Are you looking for the "best" match, or just the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many different strings are you looking for in total? If it's only a small number and/or you have a complete list somewhere already, and you don't need to be able to deal with typos, you could perhaps put together a set of formulas using the FIND function.

If you do need to be able to deal with typos, this is a lot harder - you'd need to using something like [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) to try and guess what people meant to type.